Computing the CDF associated to a random variable, which is neither discrete nor continuous, by using the pushforward measure and transfer theorem.
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $Z$ a real-valued random variable on this space to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
Let $Z\sim \frac{1}{3}\delta_{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{2}{3}\lambda(\cdot \cap [0,1])$
where $\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the Dirac delta at $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
I want to calculate the cumulative distribution function of this distribution. Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$\mathbb{P}(Z\leq t) = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t]}(Z)\right]=\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t]}\left(Z(\omega)\right)\mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t]}(z)\mathbb{P}_{Z}(dz)$$
where the last equality is due to the transfer theorem. At this point I need to compute/substitute in the push-forward measure induced by $Z$, defined for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as
$$\mathbb{P}_Z(B) = \mathbb{P}\left(\right\{Z\in B\left\}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z^{-1}(B)\right)$$
Is it correct to say that
$$\tag{*}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t]}(z)\mathbb{P}_{Z}(dz) = \frac{1}{3}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t]}(z)\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}(dz) + \frac{2}{3}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t]\cap[0,1]}(z)\lambda(dz)$$
and then conclude that this is equal to
$$\frac{1}{3}\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if } t\geq \frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & \mbox{if } t<\frac{1}{2}\end{cases} \quad+\quad \frac{2}{3} \begin{cases}0 & \mbox{if } t<0\\ t & \mbox{if } t\in[0,1]\\ 1 & \mbox{if } t>1\end{cases}$$
$$ = \begin{cases}0 & \mbox{if }t<0\\ \frac{2}{3}t & \mbox{if }t\in[0,\frac{1}{2})\\ \frac{2}{3}t + \frac{1}{3} & \mbox{if }t\in[\frac{1}{2}, 1]\\ 1 & \mbox{if }t>1\end{cases}$$
Intuitively, I can see that this is the correct expression for $F_Z(t)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq t)$ but I want to be sure my proof is completely rigorous.

It looks correct to me. You can also write $P(Z\le t)=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}((-\infty, t])+\frac{2}{3}\operatorname{max}(\operatorname{min}(1,t),0)$

@user408858 thanks for confirming it's correct; do you agree that that equation tagged with (*) is correct? I.e., I can directly replace $\mathbb{P}Z(dz)$ with $\frac{1}{3}\delta{\frac{1}{2}}(dz) + \frac{2}{3}\lambda(dz\cap[0,1])$?

Yes, I would interpret it like this. Similarly, if you say for example that $Z\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, you do the same with $\mathbb{P}Z(dz)=1{[0,1]}(z)\lambda(dz)=\lambda(dz\cap[0,1])$. You could also write $\mathbb{P}_Z=\lambda(\cdot\cap[0,1])$ in that case. Note that the sum of measures (your inital question) is defined by taking the sum of the evaluation, i.e. $(\mu+\nu)(A)=\mu(A)+\nu(A)$ for a measurable set $A$.
